# How to display the result of my query on a datagridview in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have 2 xml files : 
one is the large log file (raw data) that i need to filter, 
the other one is used as an configuration file to specify my queries to filter the data from the large log files.
this is how my two xml files look like :

**The large log file that needs to be filtered (just a small part of it is shown below)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Logging S="T006" version="2" >
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="22" ID="Opened" Msg="some text"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="76" ID="Auth"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="60" ID="Up"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="22" ID="Opened" Msg="some text"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="96" ID="Locked"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="84" ID="Done"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="57" ID="Idle"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="10" ID="Inspected" Pos="12"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="148" ID="Started"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Error" id="38" ID="TechError" Msg="too low"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Error" id="38" ID="TechError" Msg="too large"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Error" id="38" ID="TechError" Msg="disabled"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Error" id="38" ID="TechError" Msg="disabled"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Error" id="87" ID="Validation"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="data" id="31" ID="Update" Path="~/Status/" From="T121003" To="T121637"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="data" id="31" ID="Update" Path="~/Status/" From="1" To="0"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Warning" id="24" ID="Problem" Pos="12"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Warning" id="26" ID="UI" Msg="popup"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Warning" id="23" ID="Update" Path="Startup" From="1" To="0"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Info" id="58" ID="System"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="Error" id="20" ID="Log" Msg="failed"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="System" id="50" ID="System"/>
<Log Date="2018-11-21" Severity="System" id="51" ID="Memory" />
</Logging>
```

**In below is the xml I want to use to make my query statements from (as a config file)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Statuscodes xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Statuscode value="S01" text="Status code S01 ">
    <Triggers id="1">
      <Trigger searchField="Severity" searchText="Error" /> 
      <Trigger searchField="ID" searchText="TechError" /> 
    </Triggers>
    <Causes>
      <Cause shortText="this is the cause" longText="This is a very long description....." />
    </Causes>
    <Solutions>
      <Solution value="SOL01" description="Description of solution" solutionSteps="Follow these steps..." page="2" />
      <Solution value="SOL02" description="Description of solution 2" solutionSteps="or something else" page="3" />
    </Solutions>
  </Statuscode>
  <Statuscode value="S02" text="Status code S02">
    <Triggers id="2">
      <Trigger searchField="Severity" searchText="Error" /> 
      <Trigger searchField="ID" searchText="TechError" /> 
      <Trigger searchField="Msg" searchText="disabled" /> 
    </Triggers>
    <Causes>
      <Cause shortText="2-this is the cause" longText="This is a very long description....." />
    </Causes>
    <Solutions>
      <Solution value="2-SOL01" description="Description of solution" solutionSteps="Follow URL" page="2" />
      <Solution value="2-SOL02" description="Description of solution 2" solutionSteps="Do something else" page="3" />
    </Solutions>
  </Statuscode>
</Statuscodes>
```

My c# code so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private List<StatusCode> statusCodes = new List<StatusCode>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\LargeLogFile.xml");

        var errorLogDataset = new DataSet();
        errorLogDataset.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\configFile.xml");

        foreach (DataRow result in errorLogDataset.Tables["Statuscode"].Rows)
        {
            var statusCode = new StatusCode
            {
                Code = result["value"].ToString(),
                Text = result["text"].ToString()
            };

            var MyQuery = String.Empty;

            foreach (DataRow resultTrigger in errorLogDataset.Tables["Trigger"].Select("Triggers_Id = " + result[0].ToString()))
            {
                var trigger = new Trigger
                {
                    SearchField = resultTrigger["searchField"].ToString(),
                    SearchText = resultTrigger["searchText"].ToString()
                };

                statusCode.Triggers.Add(trigger);

// Questions: is this the right way/syntax to make MyQuery statement?
                MyQuery += trigger.SearchField + " = '" + trigger.SearchText + "' AND ";

            }

            MyQuery = MyQuery.TrimEnd(" AND ".ToCharArray());

//Question: can I pass MyQuery to Select like this?
            DataRow[] temp = dataSet.Tables["Log"].Select(MyQuery);

            statusCodes.Add(statusCode);
            var bindingSource = new BindingSource
            {
                DataSource = dataSet,
                DataMember = "Log"
            };

            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
        }
    }
}

class Trigger
{
    public string SearchField { get; set; }
    public string SearchText { get; set; }
}

class StatusCode
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public List<Trigger> Triggers { get; private set; }

    public StatusCode()
    {
        Triggers = new List<Trigger>();
    }
}
```

My intention is to retrieve the MyQuery result data from dataset and display the rows and columns in a gridview. so this way I filter the large log file ans see only what I select. 
by breakpoint i can see :

- the result of MyQuery = "Severity = 'Error' AND ID ='TechError'"
- errorLogDataset creates 7 tables: {Statuscode,Triggers, Trigger, Causes, Cause, Solutions, Solution} . Although I don't have attribute Triggers_Id in my xml file , but running the code creates this column in Triggers table. the same as Statuscode_Id for Statuscode table and so on for Solutions. Why is that?
- in temp I get all the rows from LogFile , not only the rows I selected in MyQuery, how can I get the result data of MyQuery from the LogFile and display only those rows in datagridview?

I know there are plenty of source  and exmaples about datagridview and LINQ and filtering but I can not find some answer more specific and similar to my situation here. Please give me advise, what I'm doing wrong in my code?.
Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Globalization;


namespace StatusTable
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string LOG_XML = @"C:\Users\LargeLogFile.xml";
        const string STATUS_XML = @"C:\Users\configFile.xml";
        enum Logic
        {
            AND,
            OR
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable logging = new DataTable();
            logging.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            logging.Columns.Add("Severity", typeof(string));
            logging.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
            logging.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            logging.Columns.Add("Msg", typeof(string));

            XDocument docLog = XDocument.Load(LOG_XML);

            foreach (XElement log in docLog.Descendants("Log"))
            {
                DateTime date = (DateTime)log.Attribute("Date");
                string severity = (string)log.Attribute("Severity");
                string id = (string)log.Attribute("id");
                string ID = (string)log.Attribute("ID");
                string msg = (string)log.Attribute("Msg");

                logging.Rows.Add(new object[] { date, severity, id, ID, msg });
            }


            XDocument docStatus = XDocument.Load(STATUS_XML);
            Logic logic = Logic.AND;
            foreach (XElement Statuscode in docStatus.Descendants("Statuscode"))
            {

                DataTable status = null;
                List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> searchFields = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
                foreach (XElement trigger in Statuscode.Descendants("Trigger"))
                {
                    string searchField = (string)trigger.Attribute("searchField");
                    string searchText = (string)trigger.Attribute("searchText");

                    switch (searchField)
                    {
                        case "Date":
                            // logging.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>(searchField) == (DateTime)trigger.Attribute(searchText)).CopyToDataTable(status, LoadOption.Upsert);
                            searchFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(searchField, (DateTime)trigger.Attribute("searchText")));
                            break;
                        default:
                            //logging.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>(searchField) == searchText).CopyToDataTable(status, LoadOption.Upsert);
                            searchFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(searchField, (string)trigger.Attribute("searchText")));
                            break;
                    }

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = status;

                }
                switch (logic)
                {
                    case Logic.AND:
                        status = logging.AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(x => searchFields.All(field => (field.Value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime)) ? x.Field<DateTime>(field.Key) == (DateTime)field.Value : x.Field<string>(field.Key) == (string)field.Value))
                            .CopyToDataTable();
                        break;

                    case Logic.OR:
                        status = logging.AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(x => searchFields.Any(field => (field.Value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime)) ? x.Field<DateTime>(field.Key) == (DateTime)field.Value : x.Field<string>(field.Key) == (string)field.Value))
                            .CopyToDataTable();
                        break;

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created datatables that you can use as the datasource for search results.  I used Xml Linq.  The results of each search is in the datatable status.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication37
{
    enum Logic
    {
        AND,
        OR
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string LOG_XML_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        const string STATUS_XML_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private List<StatusCode> statusCodes = new List<StatusCode>();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataTable errorLogDatatable = new DataTable();
            errorLogDatatable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            errorLogDatatable.Columns.Add("Severity", typeof(string));
            errorLogDatatable.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
            errorLogDatatable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            errorLogDatatable.Columns.Add("Msg", typeof(string));

            XDocument docLog = XDocument.Load(LOG_XML_FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement log in docLog.Descendants("Log"))
            {
                DateTime date = (DateTime)log.Attribute("Date");
                string severity = (string)log.Attribute("Severity");
                string id = (string)log.Attribute("id");
                string ID = (string)log.Attribute("ID");
                string msg = (string)log.Attribute("Msg");

                errorLogDatatable.Rows.Add(new object[] { date, severity, id, ID, msg });
            }

            XDocument docStatus = XDocument.Load(STATUS_XML_FILENAME);
            Logic logic = Logic.AND;
            foreach (XElement Statuscode in docStatus.Descendants("Statuscode"))
            {
                StatusCode statusCode = new StatusCode()
                {
                    Code = (string)Statuscode.Attribute("value"),
                    Text = (string)Statuscode.Attribute("text")
                };
                statusCodes.Add(statusCode);
                DataTable status = null;
                foreach (XElement trigger in Statuscode.Descendants("Trigger"))
                {

                    string searchField = (string)trigger.Attribute("searchField");
                    string searchText = (string)trigger.Attribute("searchText");

                    statusCode.Triggers.Add(new Trigger() { SearchField = searchField, SearchText = (string)trigger.Attribute("searchText") });
                }

                switch (logic)
                {
                    case Logic.AND:
                        status = errorLogDatatable.AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(x => statusCode.Triggers.All(field => x.Field<string>(field.SearchField) == field.SearchText))
                            .CopyToDataTable();
                        break;
                    case Logic.OR:
                        status = errorLogDatatable.AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(x => statusCode.Triggers.Any(field => x.Field<string>(field.SearchField) == field.SearchText))
                            .CopyToDataTable();
                        break;
                }

                var bindingSource = new BindingSource
                {
                    DataSource = status,
                };

                dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;

            }
        }
    }

    class Trigger
    {
        public string SearchField { get; set; }
        public string SearchText { get; set; }
    }

    class StatusCode
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public List<Trigger> Triggers { get; private set; }

        public StatusCode()
        {
            Triggers = new List<Trigger>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am making a windows form application, your code is for console, how can I display these tables on datagridview?

Comment: The code will drop into a form project provided you add the two Xml library using statement at top of module.  Then manually add to form a DGV.  Then all you have to due is add one statement : datagridviedw1.DataSource = logging;  Each time through the last for loop I create a new table.  I assume each Status is a diffrent table.

Comment: I get all the rows from the LogFile not only the filtered rows (in the switch case)

Comment: Sorry.  It should of been  : datagridviedw1.DataSource = status;

Comment: Do you want an "Or"ing or an "And"ing of the status?  The code is doing an Or.  I change code From : SearchField To : SearchText in the DateTime case.

Comment: yes I think I eventually need mre conditions, for example if I want to also have the solutions for each error do i need to add more case in the switch block ? or there is a more efficient way with And/Or as you mentioned?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but now I get **System.InvalidOperationException: 'The source contains no DataRows.'** at case LOGIC.AND

Comment: I ran sample xml files with and an it does return data.  You may need to add test for status == null when there are no results.

Comment: I uploaded my last version code , you can see above, but still don't get result on datagrid , I get **System.InvalidOperationException: 'The source contains no DataRows.'** at case LOGIC.AND

Comment: I updated code to work with a form and combined your code and my code together.

Comment: the source still contatins no datarows! I think maybe my xml file is not in a right format . seems like it can't access the Descendants and/or the Elements.

Comment: Did you change my code?  Are you using the XML files posted?

Comment: I did update my code based on your latest update code, and yes I am using the xmls I posted

Comment: My code works.  I do not know what difference you have in your code.  So I can't solve this issue.  DO NOT use the errorLogDataset.ReadXml() method.  It creates a DataTable that is not usable.